# Does the side of Hardibacker cement board really matter?

Tags: tile, cement-board

I saw somewhere that the rough side should face out in case of thinset and smooth in case of mastic. I hung some boards randomly before knowing so some smooth sides are facing out and I'll be using thinset.

Does it matter to the extent that I really need to redo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [**James Hardie Website FAQ**](https://www.jameshardie.com/product-support/resource-center/frequently-asked-questions#hardiebacker-faq), either side is fine to use. However, they recommend smooth side to be up and nailed every 8" on center.

Comment: I agree. They put a little more effort into finishing one side more smoothly just to make troweling easier, but it won't affect the outcome of the project.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need to redo, correct?

Comment: Not unless you are just really OCD and it will keep you up nights.

Comment: I am slightly OCD, LOL